# Javascript code output differs when ran from node.js shell and from a file

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have this strange behavior of node.js. Basically the title says it all, I would only like to add, that this wasn't the case before, with the exactly the same code.
I suspect that this started to happen after I ran `sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local/lib/node_modules` because I wanted to install typescript and got writing permissions error, however I cannot be 100% sure. Interestingly enough my test passes, and eventually everything works fine and the result is correct, but I don't know why my `console.log()` outputs are different. What I get when I put code in node shell and `console.log` it is a concatenated string from recursive calls. When I run code from a file, I only get the string from the first call.
Here's my code:

```js
const fields = {
    0: "D:0:0:0:1:20:9",
    1: "D:1:0:22:1:95:9",
    2: "D:2:0:117:1:27:9"
};

function getRequiredFields(key, trailing=false) {
    // key is a number
    if (typeof trailing !== "boolean") {
        throw new Error("<trailing> must be of type 'boolean'. Default is false");
    }

    if (typeof key === "number" && !fields[key]) {
        throw new Error("Field is not defined: <key> must be in range [0, 9]");
    }

    if (typeof key !== "number") {
        throw new Error("<key> must be a number");
    }

    const lastByte = trailing ? "\r" : "";

    if (key === 0) {
        return fields[key] + lastByte;
    } else {
        return getRequiredFields(key-1) + "\r" + fields[key] + lastByte;
    }
};

console.log(getRequiredKeys(2, true));
```

and here's my test (mocha+chai):

```js
describe("Expects a positive number to build required fields, the optional 2nd argument puts a trailing carriage return if true, default is false", () => {
    it("Returns a combined string for required fields", () => {
        expect(getRequiredFields(2)).to.be.a("string");
        expect(getRequiredFields(2, true)).to.equal("D:0:0:0:1:20:9\rD:1:0:22:1:95:9\rD:2:0:117:1:27:9\r");
        expect(getRequiredFields(2, false)).to.equal("D:0:0:0:1:20:9\rD:1:0:22:1:95:9\rD:2:0:117:1:27:9");
    });
    it("Throws an error if <trailing> is not a boolean", () => {
        expect(getRequiredFields.bind(this, 10, "foo")).to.throw("<trailing> must be of type 'boolean'");
    });
    it("Throws an error if <key> is higher than 9", () => {
        expect(getRequiredFields.bind(this, 10, true)).to.throw("Field is not defined: <key> must be in range [0, 9]");
    });
    it("Throws an error if <key> is NaN", () => {
        expect(getRequiredFields.bind(this, "f", false)).to.throw("<key> must be a number");
    });
});
```

Comment: How do you *run code from a file*?

Comment: By this I meant when you type `node myFile.js` in terminal window as opposed to when you type and run the code in node shell (or a browser console) .

Comment: there is no `console.log` in you code. please include complete code. see [mcve]

Comment: Appologies, eddited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is the control character `\r` (carriage return), which move the cursor to the leftmost point, so the further characters overwrite existing ones. Since this only effect output, the real content of the `string` is not effected, so all thing should be fine.

If you intended to use newline, you should use `\n` instead (or `require('os').EOL` for OS-specific one).

---

You can also try out the following, which would output `789456` or `123456789` depend on the enviroment.

```js
console.log('123456\r789')
```